# Magento not loading XML config from costum module

Tags: xml

I have a module Some_Costum with path **app/code/local/Some** :

[image]

The config is : https://gist.github.com/teosz/741a27242b547c277845

And in **app/code/etc/modules/Some_Custom.xml** :

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Adve_Custom>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Adve_Custom>
    </modules>
</config>`

But is not loading for checkout context,
Any help ?

Comment: what do you mean not loading ? please share some details.

Comment: loading - not showing in ```Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default');```

Answer (score 1):

The top part of your configuration needs to be placed in `app/etc/modules/Some_Custom.xml` leaving only the version node in your existing `config.xml`:

**Some_Custom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Some_Custom>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Some_Custom>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Some_Custom>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Some_Custom>
    </modules>
```

Comment: i've tried that, still not working

Comment: clear cache?? and add the rest of config.xml global/resources/some_custom_setup/setup http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table